# How to make a Graph on VueJS

Tags: node.js, graph, vue.js

Am trying to make a graph with data received from an API and put this on a graph (https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045) - Force-Directed Graph

However I am unsure on how this is done on VueJs or if there is a simpler tool to do this?

D3 Force-Directed Graph seems a bit complicated, maybe there is a library already that does this out of the box?

Comment: Herr you go https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-d3

Comment: take a look into https://github.com/johnnynotsolucky/samples/tree/master/vuejs-d3  you can look more demos on https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mentioned `vue-d3` package from the comment is just adding D3 to the Vue prototype so it is accessible with `this.$d3`.

I've tested that package but it wasn't working with my D3 version. Looks like a casing issue (D3 instead of d3). So I've added the prototype manually.

I don't know if there is an easier library for creating a force graph but please have a look at the demo below or this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/cgqdLLsq/).

I've modified the example from your link to create a force directed graph. The demo is working but as you've mentioned it's pretty complicated.
Also binding from SVG to Vue.js model could be improved. But I couldn't find a better way to do it.

For example adding a new node on click is not working with just adding a new node to the array but this should be the goal for a Vue.js component. The SVG graph should automatically update once the data changes.

At the moment, nodes and links in Vue.js are not used in the component because I don't know how to add the updating of the graph.

If you figured out how to add the updating with the model data, please let me know. Refreshing the whole chart is pretty easy by deleting the SVG and re-create it. (see reload button)

```js
// https://unpkg.com/vue-d3@0.1.0 --> only adds d3 to Vue.prototype but it wasn't working as expected (d3 is lower case)
Vue.prototype.$d3 = d3;
const URL = 'https://demo5147591.mockable.io/miserables'; // data copied from below link because of jsonp support

//'https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/4062045/5916d145c8c048a6e3086915a6be464467391c62/miserables.json';
//console.log(window.d3);
const d3ForceGraph = {
  template: `
  <div>
    {{mousePosition}}
    <button @click="reload">reload</button>
    <svg width="600" height="600" 
     @mousemove="onMouseMove($event)"></svg>
  </div>
  `,
  data() {
    return {
      nodes: [],
      links: [],
      simulation: undefined,
      mousePosition: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.loadData(); // initially load json
  },
  methods: {
    // load data
    loadData() {
      this.$svg = $(this.$el).find('svg');
        let svg = this.$d3.select(this.$svg.get(0)), //this.$d3.select("svg"),
          width = +svg.attr("width"),
          height = +svg.attr("height");
        //console.log($(this.$el).find('svg').get(0));

        this.simulation = this.$d3.forceSimulation()
          .force("link", this.$d3.forceLink().id(function(d) {
            return d.id;
          }))
          .force("charge", this.$d3.forceManyBody())
          .force("center", this.$d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));
        let color = this.$d3.scaleOrdinal(this.$d3.schemeCategory20);
        $.getJSON(URL, (graph) => {
          //d3.json("miserables.json", function(error, graph) { // already loaded
          //if (error) throw error; // needs to be implemented differently
          let nodes = graph.nodes;
          let links = graph.links;
          
          let link = svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "links")
            .selectAll("line")
            .data(links) //graph.links)
            .enter().append("line")
            .attr("stroke-width", function(d) {
              return Math.sqrt(d.value);
            });

          let node = svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "nodes")
            .selectAll("circle")
            .data(nodes) //graph.nodes)
            .enter().append("circle")
            .attr("r", 5)
            .attr("fill", function(d) {
              return color(d.group);
            })
            .call(this.$d3.drag()
              .on("start", this.dragstarted)
              .on("drag", this.dragged)
              .on("end", this.dragended));

          node.append("title")
            .text(function(d) {
              return d.id;
            });

          this.simulation
            .nodes(graph.nodes)
            .on("tick", ticked);

          this.simulation.force("link")
            .links(links); //graph.links);

          function ticked() {
            link
              .attr("x1", function(d) {
                return d.source.x;
              })
              .attr("y1", function(d) {
                return d.source.y;
              })
              .attr("x2", function(d) {
                return d.target.x;
              })
              .attr("y2", function(d) {
                return d.target.y;
              });

            node
              .attr("cx", function(d) {
                return d.x;
              })
              .attr("cy", function(d) {
                return d.y;
              });
          }
        })
      },
      reload() {
        //console.log('reloading...');
        this.$svg.empty(); // clear svg --> easiest way to re-create the force graph.
        this.loadData();
      },
      // mouse events
      onMouseMove(evt) {
        //console.log(evt, this)
        this.mousePosition = {
          x: evt.clientX,
          y: evt.clientY
        }
      },
      // drag event handlers
      dragstarted(d) {
        if (!this.$d3.event.active) this.simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
        d.fx = d.x;
        d.fy = d.y;
      },
      dragged(d) {
        d.fx = this.$d3.event.x;
        d.fy = this.$d3.event.y;
      },
      dragended(d) {
        if (!this.$d3.event.active) this.simulation.alphaTarget(0);
        d.fx = null;
        d.fy = null;
      }
  }
};

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {}
  },
  components: {
    d3ForceGraph
  }
});
```

```css
.links line {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: 0.6;
}

.nodes circle {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.8.0/d3.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.6/vue.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <d3-force-graph></d3-force-graph>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I answered another question on vue + d3 by providing an example of a [d3 force graph with vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43250096/3361579).

d3.js is now split in small modules and specific computations are isolated in small components like [d3-force](https://github.com/d3/d3-force). SVG can be drawn in a component template like any other HTML structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use vue-d3-network

`npm install vue-d3-network`

see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/emii/ru24unsz/)

html:
```

```
    <head>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/vue"> 
       </script>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://rawgit.com/emiliorizzo/vue-d3-network/master/dist/vue-d3-network.css">
       <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/emiliorizzo/vue-d3-network/master/dist/vue-d3-network.umd.js"></script>
    </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app">
    <d3-network :net-nodes="nodes" :net-links="links" :options="options">
    </d3-network>
  </div>
  </body>
```

```

javascript:
```

```
var D3Network = window['vue-d3-network']
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    D3Network
  },
  data () {
    return {
      nodes: [
        { id: 1, name: 'my node 1' },
        { id: 2, name: 'my node 2' },
        { id: 3, _color:'orange' },
        { id: 4 },
        { id: 5 },
        { id: 6 },
        { id: 7 },
        { id: 8 },
        { id: 9 }
      ],
      links: [
        { sid: 1, tid: 2, _color:'red' },
        { sid: 2, tid: 8, _color:'f0f' },
        { sid: 3, tid: 4,_color:'rebeccapurple' },
        { sid: 4, tid: 5 },
        { sid: 5, tid: 6 },
        { sid: 7, tid: 8 },
        { sid: 5, tid: 8 },
        { sid: 3, tid: 8 },
        { sid: 7, tid: 9 }
      ],
      options:
      {
        force: 3000,
        nodeSize: 20,
        nodeLabels: true,
        linkWidth:5
      }
    }
  },
})
```

```